# Boolean operations on constraints in Google or-tools library

Tags: c#, or-tools, constraint-programming, boolean-operations, cp-sat

I'm beginner in constraint programming and I'm using [Google or-tools library](https://code.google.com/p/or-tools/) in my c# program.

I want to add following constraint to my solver:

> ((t1 >= 12  && t1 <= 15) || (t2 >= 16 && t2 <= 18)) && ( t1 + t2 ) < 30

So I write following piece of code in c#:

```
var solver = new Solver("My_CP_Colver");
var t1 = solver.MakeIntVar(12, 20,"t1");
var t2 = solver.MakeIntVar(12, 20,"t2");

solver.Add(???)//<-((t1 >= 12 && t1 <= 15)||(t2 >= 16 && t2 <= 18)) && ( t1 + t2 ) < 30
```

Any help to make above constraint please?

Answer (score 10):

My language is python, I think it should easy translate follow pytho code to C#.

```
model = cp_model.CpModel()

t1 = model.NewIntVar(12, 20, "t1")
t1_bool_ge = model.NewBoolVar("t1_bool_ge")
t1_bool_le = model.NewBoolVar("t1_bool_le")
t1_bool_and =  model.NewBoolVar("t1_bool_and")
tmp_t1 = []
tmp_t1.append(t1_bool_ge)
tmp_t1.append(t1_bool_le)
model.Add(t1 >= 12).OnlyEnforceIf(t1_bool_ge) # t1 >=12
model.Add(t1 <= 15).OnlyEnforceIf(t1_bool_le) # t1 <= 15
model.Add(t1_bool_and==1).OnlyEnforceIf(tmp_t1) # (t1 >=12)&&(t1 <= 15)

t2 = model.NewIntVar(12, 20, "t2")
t2_bool_ge = model.NewBoolVar("t2_bool_ge")
t2_bool_le = model.NewBoolVar("t2_bool_le")
t2_bool_and =  model.NewBoolVar("t2_bool_and")
tmp_t2 = []
tmp_t2.append(t2_bool_ge)
tmp_t2.append(t2_bool_le)
model.Add(t2 >= 16).OnlyEnforceIf(t2_bool_ge) # t2 >=16
model.Add(t2 <= 18).OnlyEnforceIf(t2_bool_le) # t2 <= 18
model.Add(t2_bool_and==1).OnlyEnforceIf(tmp_t2) #(t2 >=16) && (t2 <=18)

tmp_t1_t2 = []
tmp_t1_t2.append(t2_bool_and)
tmp_t1_t2.append(t1_bool_and)
model.Add(sum(tmp_t1_t2)==1) #((t1 >=12)&&(t1 <= 15))||((t2 >=16) && (t2 <=18))

model.Add(t1 + t2 < 30) # ( t1 + t2 ) < 30
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Google or-tools library does not provide rich logical constraints. If you can develop your implementation in Java, I recommend you to use [Choco Solver](http://www.choco-solver.org/) which includes a SAT solver with extensive number of SAT constraints.

The current way of formulating logical constraints in Google or-tools is converting them into linear constraints. It would be better to check [this](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~dacatanz/Site/Teaching_Comb_Opt_files/Binary%20variables.pdf) first to understand the concept of transformation, then, have a look at [Who killed Agatha](http://www.hakank.org/or-tools/who_killed_agatha.cs) example from HakanK. Here a part of this implementation related to logical constraints :

```
//   if (i != j) =>
//       ((richer[i,j] = 1) <=> (richer[j,i] = 0))
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    if (i != j) {
      solver.Add((richer[i, j]==1) - (richer[j, i]==0) == 0);
    }
  }
}
```

You can also check [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/or-tools-discuss/jIKeJDUxSrE).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MakeMin` and `MakeMax` to encode the conjunctions and disjunctions respectively. Doing so for each piece, you end up with something like the following:

```cs
var solver = new Solver("MY_CP_Solver");
var t1 = solver.MakeIntVar(12, 20, "t1");
var t1ge = solver.MakeGreaterOrEqual(t1, 12);
var t1le = solver.MakeLessOrEqual(t1, 15);
var t1both = solver.MakeMin(t1ge, t1le);

var t2 = solver.MakeIntVar(12, 20, "t2");
var t2ge = solver.MakeGreaterOrEqual(t2, 16);
var t2le = solver.MakeLessOrEqual(t2, 18);
var t2both = solver.MakeMin(t2ge, t2le);
var or = solver.MakeMax(t1both, t2both);

solver.Add(or == 1);
solver.Add(t1 + t2 < 30);

var db = solver.MakePhase(new[] {t1, t2}, Solver.CHOOSE_FIRST_UNBOUND, Solver.ASSIGN_MIN_VALUE);
solver.Solve(db);

while (solver.NextSolution())
    Console.WriteLine($"t1: {t1.Value()}, t2: {t2.Value()}");
```

Output:

```
t1: 12, t2: 12
t1: 12, t2: 13
t1: 12, t2: 14
t1: 12, t2: 15
t1: 12, t2: 16
t1: 12, t2: 17
t1: 13, t2: 12
t1: 13, t2: 13
t1: 13, t2: 14
t1: 13, t2: 15
t1: 13, t2: 16
t1: 14, t2: 12
t1: 14, t2: 13
t1: 14, t2: 14
t1: 14, t2: 15
t1: 15, t2: 12
t1: 15, t2: 13
t1: 15, t2: 14
```

In particular, the first constraint in your disjunction is always active.

Using the newer `Google.OrTools.Sat.CpSolver`, you could do something like the following where we introduce an auxiliary boolean `b`, which has the property that it ensures that at least one of the clauses in the disjunction is satisfied:

```cs
var model = new CpModel();
var t1 = model.NewIntVar(12, 20, "t1");
var t2 = model.NewIntVar(12, 20, "t2");
var b = model.NewBoolVar("First constraint active");

model.Add(t1 >= 12).OnlyEnforceIf(b);
model.Add(t1 <= 15).OnlyEnforceIf(b);
model.Add(t2 >= 16).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not());
model.Add(t2 <= 18).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not());
model.Add(t1 + t2 < 30);
var solver = new CpSolver();
var cb = new SolutionPrinter(new [] { t1, t2 });
solver.SearchAllSolutions(model, cb);
```

Here, the printer is defined as follows:

```cs
public class SolutionPrinter : CpSolverSolutionCallback
{
    public VarArraySolutionPrinter(IntVar[] v) => this.v = v;
    public override void OnSolutionCallback() => Console.WriteLine($"t1: {Value(v[0])}, t2: {Value(v[1])}");
    private readonly IntVar[] v;
}
```

Note that this will find the same `(t1, t2)`-pairs multiple times (but with different values of `b`)