# Google OR tools: how to evaluate complex or multi-level boolean constraints

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

**Set up**

I am using the google OR tools as a constraint programming solver:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
```

I have defined the following BoolVars

```
model = cp_model.CpModel()
a = model.NewBoolVar("a")
b = model.NewBoolVar("b")
c = model.NewBoolVar("c")
d = model.NewBoolVar("d")
e = model.NewBoolVar("e")
f = model.NewBoolVar("f")
g = model.NewBoolVar("g")
```

**Question**

I need to add a complex boolean constraint to the model. Something like

```
(a || b) && (d || e) == g
```

*How can I add a complex boolean constraint like this to the model?*

**PS:** I couldn't find this information immediately online, but found a solution based on an answer I got on a related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553100/constraint-optimization-in-python-with-or-tools-how-to-enforce-a-multi-level-co/70554356?noredirect=1#comment124730209_70554356) and another related problem of another person [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814935/boolean-operations-on-constraints-in-google-or-tools-library). I summarize my findings here in Q&A style in the hope that they will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 5):

This kind of constraint cannot be added at once to the model. The constraint needs to be split up in its components (and & or gates). Each basic component needs to be set equal to a new BoolVar. These are then combined to add the final constraint.

**Breakdown to basic components**

We'll do this as follows:

```
(a || b) == c
(d || e) == f
(c && f) == g
```

This last equation is equivalent to the original equation:

```
(a || b) && (d || e) == g
```

**Storing basic constraints in new BoolVars**

An "OR" type of equation can be evaluated with the following function:

```
def evaluate_or(a, b, c):
    # Either a or b or both must be 1 if c is 1.
    model.AddBoolOr([a, b]).OnlyEnforceIf(c)

    # The above line is not sufficient, as no constraints are defined if c==0 (see reference documentation of
    # "OnlyEnforceIf". We therefore add another line to cover the case when c==0:

    # a and b must both be 0 if c is 0
    model.AddBoolAnd([a.Not(), b.Not()]).OnlyEnforceIf([c.Not()])
```

An "AND" type of equation can similarily be evaluated with the following function:

```
def evaluate_and(a, b, c):
    # Both a and b must be 1 if c is 1
    model.AddBoolAnd([a, b]).OnlyEnforceIf(c)

    #What happens if c is 0? This is still undefined thus let us add another line:

    # Either a or b or both must be 0 if c is 0.
    model.AddBoolOr([a.Not(), b.Not()]).OnlyEnforceIf(c.Not())
```

In this specific case the basic constraints are twice an OR gate. We store them in c and f:

```
evaluate_or(a, b, c)
evaluate_or(d, e, f)
```

**Adding the complex constraint**

This is now really simple and can be done using the BoolVars from the previous step and an AND gate:

```
evaluate_and(c, f, g)
```

**Discussion**

Any complex constraint can be added using intermediary BoolVars and the defined OR and AND gate functions above. The constraint just needs to be broken down into its basic components.

**Full program**

This is the full program:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()
a = model.NewBoolVar("a")
b = model.NewBoolVar("b")
c = model.NewBoolVar("c")
d = model.NewBoolVar("d")
e = model.NewBoolVar("e")
f = model.NewBoolVar("f")
g = model.NewBoolVar("g")

def evaluate_or(a, b, c):
    # Either a or b or both must be 1 if c is 1.
    model.AddBoolOr([a, b]).OnlyEnforceIf(c)

    # The above line is not sufficient, as no constraints are defined if c==0 (see reference documentation of
    # "OnlyEnforceIf". We therefore add another line to cover the case when c==0:

    # a and b must both be 0 if c is 0
    model.AddBoolAnd([a.Not(), b.Not()]).OnlyEnforceIf([c.Not()])

def evaluate_and(a, b, c):
    # Both a and b must be 1 if c is 1
    model.AddBoolAnd([a, b]).OnlyEnforceIf(c)

    #What happens if c is 0? This is still undefined thus let us add another line:

    # Either a or b or both must be 0 if c is 0.
    model.AddBoolOr([a.Not(), b.Not()]).OnlyEnforceIf(c.Not())

#Add the constraints
evaluate_or(a, b, c)
evaluate_or(d, e, f)
evaluate_and(c, f, g)


# Solve the model.
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.enumerate_all_solutions = True
status = solver.Solve(model, cp_model.VarArraySolutionPrinter([a, b, c, d, e, f, g]))
```

**Output**

The following output is obtained:

```
Solution 0, time = 0.00 s
  a = 0   b = 0   c = 0   d = 1   e = 0   f = 1   g = 0 
Solution 1, time = 0.00 s
  a = 0   b = 0   c = 0   d = 1   e = 1   f = 1   g = 0 
Solution 2, time = 0.00 s
  a = 0   b = 0   c = 0   d = 0   e = 1   f = 1   g = 0 
Solution 3, time = 0.00 s
  a = 0   b = 0   c = 0   d = 0   e = 0   f = 0   g = 0 
Solution 4, time = 0.00 s
  a = 0   b = 1   c = 1   d = 0   e = 0   f = 0   g = 0 
Solution 5, time = 0.00 s
  a = 0   b = 1   c = 1   d = 1   e = 0   f = 1   g = 1 
Solution 6, time = 0.00 s
  a = 0   b = 1   c = 1   d = 1   e = 1   f = 1   g = 1 
Solution 7, time = 0.00 s
  a = 0   b = 1   c = 1   d = 0   e = 1   f = 1   g = 1 
Solution 8, time = 0.00 s
  a = 1   b = 1   c = 1   d = 0   e = 1   f = 1   g = 1 
Solution 9, time = 0.00 s
  a = 1   b = 1   c = 1   d = 1   e = 1   f = 1   g = 1 
Solution 10, time = 0.00 s
  a = 1   b = 1   c = 1   d = 1   e = 0   f = 1   g = 1 
Solution 11, time = 0.00 s
  a = 1   b = 1   c = 1   d = 0   e = 0   f = 0   g = 0 
Solution 12, time = 0.00 s
  a = 1   b = 0   c = 1   d = 0   e = 0   f = 0   g = 0 
Solution 13, time = 0.00 s
  a = 1   b = 0   c = 1   d = 0   e = 1   f = 1   g = 1 
Solution 14, time = 0.00 s
  a = 1   b = 0   c = 1   d = 1   e = 1   f = 1   g = 1 
Solution 15, time = 0.00 s
  a = 1   b = 0   c = 1   d = 1   e = 0   f = 1   g = 1
```

Comment: The discussion in the Google OR-Tools forum under https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/zQB-_2nsgsc/m/XTmI5UE3BAAJ is also relevant for this topic. There are some suggestions on how to create custom classes that overload the `&&` and `||` operators to make it possible to simply write expressions like `(a || b) && (d || e) == g` directly.